Calculate the length of the segment joining the midpoints of $BM$ and $AC$
On the side $BC$ of a right triangle ABC m($∡=90°$) an equilateral triangle $BMC$ is constructed. If $AM = 8$.
Calculate the length of the segment joining the midpoints of $BM$ and $AC$
(Answer:4)
Itry
$\angle BCA \cong \angle AB$
$\angle ABM =90^o +60^o =150^o $
$\triangle ABM: 8^2 =AB^2+BM^2 - 2AB.AC.cos 150^o  \implies 64 = AB^2+BC^2\sqrt3.AB.BC$
How do I finish?


Is $G$ midpoint of $AC$? In this case, $BG$ is not necessarily perpendicular to $AC$.

It is perpendicular if and only if $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles right triangle. I'm wondering if it is an assumption of the problem or the image is inaccurate.

The question seems to be only possible if the triangle is a right angled isosceles triangle

Let $K$ be the midpoint of $[BC]$. Observe that we have the following:

$|GK| = \dfrac{|AB|}{2}$
$|KF| = \dfrac{|BM|}{2}$
$\angle GKF = \angle ABM = 150^\circ$

By side-angle-side similarity, we obtain $\triangle GKF \sim \triangle ABM$ with ratio $1:2$. Therefore, $$|GF| = \dfrac{|AM|}{2} = \dfrac{8}{2} = \boxed{4}.$$

Thanks for help

Since $G$ is the midpoint of the hypotenuse, then:
$$GA=GB=GC$$
must hold true. Again, since $BG\perp AC$, therefore, $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle. Therefore, we have:
$$\angle ABM=150^\circ, \angle BAM=\angle BMA=15^\circ$$
Applying sine rule to $\triangle ABM$, we get:
$$\frac{AM}{\sin\angle ABM}=\frac{AB}{\sin\angle BAM}$$
$$AB=8\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\sin 105^\circ}=8(2-\sqrt3)$$
Now, $\angle MAC=30^\circ$ and $\angle ACB=45^\circ$. Now, since $\triangle AGB$ and $\triangle BGC$ is congruent, therefore, the angle $\angle ABC$ has been bisected by $BG$, resulting $\angle GBC=45^\circ$ and so $\angle GBM=105^\circ$.

Now, mark the intersection point of $BC$ and $AM$ as $O$. Then, $\angle AOB=75^\circ$ and $\angle BOM=105^\circ$.
Consider, $\angle BGF=x$. Moreover, consider the intersection point of the dotted line and the blue line as $P$. Then since $\angle AOC=105^\circ$, you can find [as a check] $MPG=120^\circ$. Furthermore, consider $\angle BGF=x$ and the intersection point of $BC$ and $GF$ be $Q$.
For the quadrilateral $\square OPGQ$, we have $\angle G=x$ and $\angle Q=135^\circ-x$, therefore, the vertically opposite angle of $Q$ is also $135^\circ-x$.
Consider the quadrilateral $\square QMCR$, where $R$ is the intersection point of $GF$ and $AM$ , the lower right quadrilateral. Angles here includes $\angle C=60^\circ$, $\angle M=60^\circ$, $\angle Q=135^\circ-x$ and finally $F=105^\circ-x$. Then the supplementary angle of $F$ is measured to be $75^\circ-x$ that falls on the triangle $\triangle BGF$. This results that $\angle F=60^\circ$ and $\angle G=15^\circ$ in that triangle.
Now, applying sine rule to $\triangle BGF$ with $BF=4(2-\sqrt3)$, we get:
$$\frac{BF}{\sin\angle BGF}=\frac{GF}{\sin \angle GBF}$$
$$GF=4(2-\sqrt3)\times\frac{\sin 105^\circ}{\sin 15^\circ}=4$$
